# OpenMDAO ListGenerator DOEs fail when using multidimensional arrays as inputs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, openmdao

I'm having an issue with OpenMDAO where a DOE created using the ListGenerator DOE Driver will fail when the inputs are multidimensional arrays. It appears that the array is being flattened at some point, which then causes a mismatched dimensions error when assigning the input arrays. I have previously successfully used ListGenerator with scalar inputs.

Here is a small piece of code that should demonstrate the problem:

```
import openmdao.api as om
import numpy as np

# Create a subsystem with multidimensional array inputs
test_system = om.ExecComp('z = matmul(x,y)',
                          x=np.ones((3,3)),y=np.ones((3,3)),z=np.ones((3,3)))

# Single execution test
prob = om.Problem()
model = prob.model
model.add_subsystem('testSystem',test_system,promotes=['*'])
prob.setup()
prob['x'] = np.array([[1,2,3],
                      [4,5,6],
                      [7,8,9]])
prob['y'] = np.array([[9,8,7],
                      [6,5,4],
                      [3,2,1]])
prob.run_model()
print(prob['z'])

# DOE test
prob2 = om.Problem()
model2 = prob2.model
model2.add_subsystem('testSystem',test_system,promotes=['*'])
model2.add_design_var('x')
model2.add_design_var('y')
model2.add_objective('z')

prob2.setup()

case_list = [
    [['x',np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])],['y',np.array([[9,8,7],[6,5,4],[3,2,1]])]]
    ]

prob2.driver = om.DOEDriver(case_list)
prob2.driver.add_recorder(om.SqliteRecorder("cases.sql"))

prob2.run_driver()
prob2.cleanup()
```

The first problem ("prob") works as expected. The second problem ("prob2"), which should accomplish the same thing through the use of a one-case DOE, fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/josephrobinson/Documents/GitHub/thesis/work/python/testing/doe_array_test.py", line 46, in <module>
    prob2.run_driver()

  File "/Users/josephrobinson/opt/anaconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmdao/core/problem.py", line 665, in run_driver
    return self.driver.run()

  File "/Users/josephrobinson/opt/anaconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmdao/drivers/doe_driver.py", line 171, in run
    self._run_case(case)

  File "/Users/josephrobinson/opt/anaconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmdao/drivers/doe_driver.py", line 195, in _run_case
    raise(ValueError(msg))

ValueError: Error assigning x = [[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (9)
```

I am using OpenMDAO 3.8.0 with Python 3.8.5, although I saw this same error on OpenMDAO 3.4.0 before updating. I also saw the same issue with a much larger three-dimensional array.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in OpenMDAO 3.8.1 and earlier versions. It looks like we need to flatten the design var values provided to the ListGenerator before setting them in the model. I've submitted an issue on github:

https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/issues/1983

You can monitor the progress from that link.

As a workaround for now, the example you provided runs without exception if you flatten the design variables in the list:

```
  case_list = [
      [['x',np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]).flatten()],
       ['y',np.array([[9,8,7],[6,5,4],[3,2,1]]).flatten()]]
      ]
```